# How to execute my program if it encounters a None in its parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to execute my def function in a way if it encounters a None in its parameter it will return a blank space or else it will measure its length.

```
def get_display_info(dice_to_roll_again_str, dice_set_aside_str):   
    length1 =len(dice_to_roll_again_str)
    if dice_set_aside_str == None:
        return ' '
    else :
        length2 =len(dice_set_aside_str)
    if length2 != None:
        if length1 and length2 > 0:
            return "(Dice to roll again:" + str(dice_to_roll_again_str) +','+ "Dice set aside:" + str(dice_set_aside_str) + ')'
        elif length1 > 0:
            return "(Dice to roll again:" + str(dice_to_roll_again_str) + ')'
        elif length2 > 0:
            return "(Dice set aside:" + str(dice_set_aside_str) + ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

None, True and False tests are done with words:

```
if dice_set_aside_str is not None:
    return 0
```

Anything [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=iterable) without any items resolves to `False` in boolean tests. So do empty strings and so does None. This we can combine:

```
if not dice_set_aside_str:
    return 0
else:
    return len(dice_set_aside_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Reference

**1. What is the null or None Keyword**
http://pythoncentral.io/python-null-equivalent-none/

**2. format() function**
https://pyformat.info/

**3. Python Learning for Begniner**
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/  (Beginer For Best)
- https://www.learnpython.org/
- https://www.javatpoint.com/python-tutorial
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ (Coding Stadered)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html (Python InBuilt Function)

## Your Mistack

When ever check the string length so not compare with None but compare with `null, "", '', isEmpty()...etc` various function.

## Suggestion

You are write all the condition false not any condition proper so write proper condition and use coding standard so make more powerful program more reference for read python documentation.

## Solution

I give solution but not change the all condtion because i don't know what your project and what you write.

```
def get_display_info(dice_to_roll_again_str, dice_set_aside_str):   
      if dice_set_aside_str == '':
        return ' '
      else :
        length2 =len(dice_set_aside_str)

      if dice_to_roll_again_str == '':
        return ' '
      else :
        length1 =len(dice_to_roll_again_str)

      if length2 != 0 and length1!=0:
        if length1==1 and length2==1:
            return "(Dice to roll again:{}".format(str(dice_to_roll_again_str))+",Dice set aside:{}".format(str(dice_set_aside_str))+")"
        elif length1 > 1:
            return "(Dice to roll again:{}".format(str(dice_to_roll_again_str))+")"
        elif length2 > 1:
            return "(Dice set aside:{}".format(str(dice_set_aside_str))+")"

print get_display_info("vora","m")
```

Comment: i don understand about the  .format cause i am new to programming.Anyway i tested it out and it works for one parameter

Comment: but when i try to implement into the program it says indented error

Comment: Hello Adrian i add more link in my answer so first read this tutorial so easily understand or any function not understand so search on google it's give best answer...

Comment: indented error is, when you write program so any place/line space problem.
So read this documentation so you are more understanding http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3

Comment: i updated my answer so check please and try to execute code. I hope it's run successfuly.