# error when executing the program python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
   get_value =get_display_info('5 6 0','7 0 0 0 5')
   print(get_value)

def get_display_info(dice_to_roll_again_str, dice_set_aside_str):   
   length1 =len(dice_to_roll_again_str)
   d = dice_set_aside_str
   if dice_set_aside_str == None:
     return 0
   else :
     return len(dice_set_aside_str)
   if length1 and dice_set_aside_str  > 0:
     return "(Dice to roll again:" + str(dice_to_roll_again_str) +','+ 
              "Dice set aside:" + str(d) + ')'
   elif length1 > 0:
     return "(Dice to roll again:" + str(dice_to_roll_again_str) + ')'
   elif dice_set_aside_str > 0:
     return "(Dice set aside:" + str(d) + ')'
```

Why does my program stop executing upon reaching this statement?

```
if length1 and dice_set_aside_str > 0:
```

Comment: Hello Adrian, Can you explain in details what you want and explain your project so we are give best idea regarding your project and code because you are new in python and you are put second time this question in stackoverflow.

Comment: First time you are put this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108421/how-do-execute-my-program-if-it-encounter-a-none-in-its-parameter-in-python/46108894#46108894

Comment: the program is actually a stuck in the mud game where dice_value are generated randomly between 1 to 6 inclusive ,it is part of my assignment where i only required to fill in the empty def function without modify the def main function.My assignment state that for this specific problem i need to get the length of the parameter and it may something encounter none in its parameter.It is hard to show and explain in details because the algorithm is too long

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return unconditionally after this block:

```
def get_display_info(dice_to_roll_again_str, dice_set_aside_str):   
   length1 =len(dice_to_roll_again_str)
   d = dice_set_aside_str
   if dice_set_aside_str == None:
     return 0
   else :
     return len(dice_set_aside_str)
```

Comment: how should i add   a second 'if statement' after that statement.The reason why i include none to dice_set_aside_str because there are some time when it encounter none in its parameter

Comment: Put the 'else' statement in the end of the block and replace the 'if' with an 'elif' statement (I deleted an example, because it's totally messy in the comments).
if - elif - else statements are a bit like 'select case' or 'case' from some other languages.
Does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Adrian,**

## Solution

Try this below code,

```
def main():
    get_value =get_display_info('5 6 0','7 0 0 0 5')
    print "Value : ",get_value

def get_display_info(dice_to_roll_again_str, dice_set_aside_str):   

    length1 = len(dice_to_roll_again_str)
    d = dice_set_aside_str

    if dice_set_aside_str == "":
     return 0
    else :
     return len(dice_set_aside_str)

    if length1 and dice_set_aside_str  > 0:
     return "(Dice to roll again:{}".format(str(dice_to_roll_again_str))+",Dice set aside:{}".format(str(dice_set_aside_str))+")"
    elif length1 > 0:
     return "(Dice to roll again:{}".format(str(dice_to_roll_again_str))+")"
    elif dice_set_aside_str > 0:
     return "Dice set aside:{}".format(str(dice_set_aside_str))+")"

# Call the main() function
main()
# Call and Print get_display_info() function.
print "Display information : ",get_display_info("mayur","vora")
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.